# angularjs multiple nested parent children directives communication

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

I have a directive which contains a child directive which also contains a child directive, and I am trying to use the top most parents controller to access the grandchild's controller and call a function that is part of the grandchilds controller.  I am getting an error with the function being undefined.  I would like to be able to control the grandchild directive using the top most parent through the grandchilds controller.

```js
angular.module('components', [])
.controller('MyButtonController', ['$scope', function($scope){
    this.mySubButtons = [];
    
    this.addSubButtons = function(s){
        this.mySubButtons.push(s);
    }
    
}]).controller('MyButtonGroupController', ['$scope', function($scope){
    this.myButtons = [];
    this.addMyButtonCtrl = function(ctrl){
        this.myButtons.push(ctrl);
    };
    this.setName = function(name){
        //undefined function
        this.myButtons[0].setName(name);
        console.log(this.myButtons);
    }
}])
.directive('mySubButton', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope:{}, 
        require: ['^myButton', 'mySubButton'],
        template: '<div>Hello {{name}}</div>',
        controller: ['$scope', function($scope){
            $scope.name="phil";
            this.setName = function(name){
                $scope.name = name;
            }
        }],
        link: function(scope,element,attrs, ctrls){
            ctrls[0].addSubButtons(ctrls[1]);
        }
    }
})
.directive('myButton', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope:{},
            require: ['^myButtonGroup','myButton'],
            controller: 'MyButtonController',
            template: '<div><my-sub-button></my-sub-button><my-sub-button></my-sub-button></div>',
            link: function(scope,element,attrs, ctrls){
                ctrls[0].addMyButtonCtrl(ctrls[1]);
            }
        }
    })
.directive('myButtonGroup', function(){
    return {
        restrict:'E',
        scope:{},
        transclude: true,
        replace: true,
        controller: 'MyButtonGroupController',
        template: '<div ng-transclude></div>',
        link: function(scope,element, attrs, groupCtrl){
            var myButtonsCtrls = groupCtrl.myButtons;
            groupCtrl.setName('Jill');
          
        }
    }
})

angular.module('HelloApp', ['components'])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.min.js"></script>
<body  ng-app="HelloApp">
    <my-button-group>
        <my-button></my-button>
        <my-button></my-button>
    </my-button-group>
</body>
```

jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/jaLhwgbg/2/

Answer (score 0):

Use events instead and you will have much cleaner code. When dynamically modifying code you can never be sure that a function or property exists. With events you just alert something else to take action how they see fit.

So MyButtonController would `$scope.$broadcast('doSomethingMyButtonChildren')` and your mySubButton directive would take action like this `scope.$on('doSomethingMyButtonChilden', function() {})`.

The above is the best practice for cleaner, more readable, more easily testable code. However to answer your origin question your addMyButtonCtrl function has a context issue.

Wrong

```
this.mySubButtons = [];
this.addMyButtonCtrl = function(ctrl){
    this.mySubButtons.push(ctrl);
    // 'this' is refering to the closure of the function addMyButtonCtrl
    // not of the controller itself
};
```

Correct

```
this.mySubButtons = [];
this.addMyButtonCtrl = function(ctrl){
    mySubButtons.push(ctrl);
};
```

Comment: actually, it seemed that the children directives and adding their controller where fast of the top most parent controller, so after adding a timeout in the top parent controller link before I set the name seems too make it work.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't define setName in MyButtonController, which is the type that you were trying to call setName on.

http://jsfiddle.net/y2vfhzwe/

MyButtonController becomes:

```
.controller('MyButtonController', ['$scope', function($scope){
    this.mySubButtons = [];

    this.addSubButtons = function(s){
        this.mySubButtons.push(s);
    }
    this.setName = function(name) {
        this.mySubButtons[0].name = name;
    }
```